# Instances in locale declaration for Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I've declared a certain locale which fixes multiple things and am trying to declare a new locale for morphisms of the first. Here's the first locale:

```
locale presheaf = topology + Ring +
fixes 
opcatopensets ::" ('a) PosetalCategory" and
objectsmap :: "'a set ⇒ ('a, 'm) Ring_scheme" and
restrictionsmap:: "('a set ×'a set) ⇒ ('a  ⇒ 'a)"
assumes 
"opcatopensets  ≡ ⦇ Obj = {x. x ∈ T} , Mor = {(x,y)| x y. (x,y) ∈ revpo} ,
 Dom = psheafdom , Cod  = psheafcod , Id  = psheafid  , Comp = psheafcomp ⦈" and
"∀y w. w ≠ y ⟶ (psheafcomp (x,y) (w,z) = undefined)" and
"∀x. x ∉ T ⟶ (objectsmap x = undefined)" and
"∀x y.(restrictionsmap (x,y)) ∈ rHom (objectsmap x) (objectsmap y)" and
"∀ x y . (restrictionsmap (x,x) y = y) " and
"∀ x y z .  ( (restrictionsmap (y,z))∘(restrictionsmap (x,y)) = restrictionsmap(x,z) )"
```

At the end of this declaration, I get the following output:

```
locale presheaf =
  fixes T :: "'a set set" 
    and R :: "('b, 'c) Ring_scheme" 
    and opcatopensets :: "'a PosetalCategory" 
    and objectsmap :: "'a set ⇒ ('a, 'm) Ring_scheme" 
    and restrictionsmap :: "'a set × 'a set ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a" 
  assumes "presheaf T R opcatopensets objectsmap restrictionsmap"
```

So I thought I could extract from the last line what I needed in order to define a new locale involving two instances of the locale "presheaf". This is what I tried:

```
locale sheafmorphism = 
F: presheaf T  R opcatopensets F restrictionsmap + G: presheaf T R opcatopensets
G restrictionsmap 
for F and G  +
fixes morphism :: "'a set ⇒ ('a ⇒ 'a)"
assumes  (things)
```

In short, I want to fix two presheaves F and G and then fix this parameter "morphism" and assume things involving "morphism" and the "restrictionsmap" and "objectsmap" of F and G. This attempt of mine led to:

> Illegal free variables in expression: "T", "R", "opcatopensets",
>   "restrictionsmap"

I suppose I don't understand how to do this when the locale you want to instantiate fixes more than one thing. What is causing this error and how could I do what I'd like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily combine several instances of a locale into a new one, but you typically must rename the parameters of the locales and declare them accordingly with `for`. In your code, you only renamed the parameter `objectsmap` to `F` and `G` respectively, and added the prefixes `F` and `G` to refer to the two instances. However, the other parameters `T`, `R`, `opcatopensets`, and `restrictionsmap` have not been renamed and are missing in the `for` clause of the locale declaration. That is the reason for the error message. So you should add them to the `for` clause and it should work. However, both instances of the locale will use the same `T`, `R`, `opcatopensets` and `restrictionsmap`. If this is not what you intended, then you should rename them, too.

For example, the following declaration

```
locale sheafmorphism = 
  F: presheaf T1 R1 opcatopensets1 F restrictionsmap1 +
  G: presheaf T2 R2 opcatopensets2 G restrictionsmap2 
  for T1 R1 opcatopensets1 F restrictionsmap1
      T2 R2 opcatopensets2 G restrictionsmap2 +
  fixes morphism :: "'a set ⇒ ('a ⇒ 'a)"
  assumes ...
```

renames all arguments of the two instances. In contrast, the following only renames the morphism to `F` and `G`.

```
locale sheafmorphism = 
  F: presheaf T R opcatopensets F restrictionsmap +
  G: presheaf T R opcatopensets G restrictionsmap 
  for T R opcatopensets F G restrictionsmap +
  fixes morphism :: "'a set ⇒ ('a ⇒ 'a)"
  assumes ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that. How do I rename parameters in the "for" declaration? Given what you said, I tried writing                                                          " locale sheafmorphism = 
F: presheaf T  R opcatopensets F restrictionsmap + G: presheaf T R opcatopensets
G restrictionsmap 
for T R opcatopensets F restrictionsmap and G  + (...)", and that seems to have fixed that error, but it would be great to be able to refer to an "F-version" and a "G"-version of "restrictionsmap", for example.

Comment: I've added two examples of renaming to the post. You can find more explanations in the tutorial on locales available in the documentation panel.